# Does terminfo provide an option for /usr/local/share?

Tags: terminfo

Where should I install global terminfo files? Is there a `/usr/local/share/terminfo`? I would rather not pollute the distro's terminfo files in `/usr/share/terminfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I install global terminfo files?

On a typical GNU/Linux machine you should put them in `/etc/terminfo`, where they would be looked for by default.

This is the case on most Debian or Fedora/Redhat based distros, but also on Gentoo, Alpine, etc -- `infocmp -D` will tell you if that's really the case on your system. On Debian-based distros, `tic` will also write the compiled entries there by default when run as root (check with `tic -D`).

The `/etc/terminfo` directory comes in handy when you want to override a terminfo entry -- eg. to replace the `cnorm` and `cvvis` capabilities in the `linux` entry with some that don't turn the cursor blinking back on.

Other systems don't have such a nice built-in override: you'll have to create that (or other) directory by hand and point it to explicitly with the `TERMINFO` or `TERMINFO_DIRS` environment variables; also, the main terminfo directory may not be `/usr/share/terminfo/`, but `/usr/gnu/share/terminfo/` or something else. Check `man ncurses` on your system for all the details.

There are also systems (eg. FreeBSD) which do not support terminfo at all and are still using the termcap format. And, to complicate matters even more, some systems may have both a base and a "ports" implementation of ncurses, each with its own idea of what the defaults should be.

Comment: You are mistaken `/etc/terminfo` does not appear in the whole UNIX sources except for comment where it has been converted from /etc/termcap by mistake. In other words, if you are correct for Linux, this is a vendor specific deviation.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html):

- all terminfo implementations recognize the [`TERMINFO`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) variable to select a terminfo database.
- ncurses additionally recognizes a search-list of directories [`TERMINFO_DIRS`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS)
- the default location (for `TERMINFO` or `TERMINFO_DIRS`) is compiled-in, and can differ between systems.  Sometimes packagers document the location (if they override the defaults).

Usually `infocmp` (across different implementations) shows the location where it found the terminal description in a comment at the beginning of its output.

ncurses' [**`tic`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html) and [**`infocmp`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) **`-D`** option shows the locations it uses.

Further reading:

- [*How do I set up a private terminfo database?*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#home_terminfo) (ncurses FAQ)
- [*What platforms does it run on?*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#what_platforms) (ncurses FAQ)